# sort array of objects alphabetically c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, object

I am enrolled in an Object Oriented programming class and am using code::blocks as my IDE. We have a project that requires to pass an array of objects ( a Libray book array with private names and titles) into a sort array that will sort the titles or authors alphabetically. I have all the components working as they should be except the sort function. I used a sort function that I have used before in other programs but am having trouble getting it to work with this program. I am still in the beginning stages of learning how to code and would appreciate any feedback.

Header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Book
{
private:
    string title;
    string author;
public:
    Book();
    string getTitle();
    string getAuthor();
    void setTitle(string Title1);
    void setAuthor(string Author1);
};
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Library.h"

using namespace std;

//Sort function prototype
void s_sort (Book lib_books[], int n);

int main()
{
// Initializes n as the number of books
int n = 15;

//Declaration of array of objects
Book lib_books[15];

// Declartion of the private member "title" for each object
lib_books[0].setTitle("The Alchemist");
lib_books[1].setTitle("The Princess Bride");
lib_books[2].setTitle("The Catcher in the Rye");
lib_books[3].setTitle("1984");
lib_books[4].setTitle("Fahrenheit 451");
lib_books[5].setTitle("The Great Gatsby");
lib_books[6].setTitle("Poland");
lib_books[7].setTitle("The Cantebury Tales");
lib_books[8].setTitle("Leaves of Grass");
lib_books[9].setTitle("Where the Sidewalk Ends");
lib_books[10].setTitle("The Iliad");
lib_books[11].setTitle("Things to Think On");
lib_books[12].setTitle("The Grapes of Wraith");
lib_books[13].setTitle("Hop on Pop");
lib_books[14].setTitle("The Prince and the Pauper");

// Declartion of the private member "author" for each object
lib_books[0].setAuthor ("Paulo Coalho");
lib_books[1].setAuthor ("William Goldman");
lib_books[2].setAuthor ("J.D. Salinger");
lib_books[3].setAuthor ("George Orwell");
lib_books[4].setAuthor ("Ray Bradbury");
lib_books[5].setAuthor ("F. Scott Fitzgerald");
lib_books[6].setAuthor ("James A. Mitchener");
lib_books[7].setAuthor ("Chaucer");
lib_books[8].setAuthor ("Walt Whitman");
lib_books[9].setAuthor ("Shel Silverstein");
lib_books[10].setAuthor("Homer");
lib_books[11].setAuthor("Krishnamurti");
lib_books[12].setAuthor("John Steinbeck");
lib_books[13].setAuthor("Dr. Seuss");
lib_books[14].setAuthor("Mark Twain");
```

The portion of main that I'm having issues:

```
// Function to sort the books alphabetically by author
s_sort (lib_books,n);
cout << "\n";                      
// For loop to print all 15 books with author and title
for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    cout <<"  "<<setw(25)<<lib_books[i].getTitle()<< "     " <<lib_books[i].getTitle()<< "\n" ;
}
return 0;
}

//Sort function definition
void s_sort (Book::getTitle(), int n)
{
int m;
string hold;// Initializes 'hold' as a 'string' so all the characters will be used when it is sorted

for (int k=0; k<=n-1; k++)// 'For' loop sorts through the index
{
m = k;
    for (int j=k+1; j <= n-1; j++)
    {

    if (lib_books[j].getTitle() < lib_books[m].getTitle());
    //m = j;
    }

// Swaps the lib_book[].getTitle() around and uses 'hold' as a placement
hold = lib_books[m].getTitle();
lib_books[m].getTitle() = lib_books[k].getTitle();
lib_books[k].getTitle() = hold;

hold = lib_books[m].getAuthor();
lib_books[m].getAuthor() = lib_books[k].getAuthor();
lib_books[k].getAuthor() = hold;
}
}
```

Implementation file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Library.h"

using namespace std;

Book::Book()
{
    title = " ";
    author = " ";
} 
string Book::getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
string Book::getAuthor()
{
    return author;
}
void Book::setTitle(string Title1)
{
    title= Title1;
}
void Book::setAuthor(string Author1)
{
    author= Author1;
}
```

The problem that I am having is that it doesn't sort the array. It prints out the same list that was defined. I have tried to pass the array by reference but it needs a index number in the function prototype and definition.

Comment: We have no idea what `s_sort` is, where `lib_books` comes from, etc. Update your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: First, solution is 1-line using `std::sort`.  Second, we have no idea what your sort consists of.  What sorting algorithm is used?  Bubble?  Insertion Sort?  Selection sort?  Quicksort?  Merge sort? some other sort algorithm?  By leaving out the sort code, that is a *huge* piece missing from your question.

Comment: Sorry about that guys.. Code is updated

Comment: First, you have a semicolon after the `if` in the swap.  That shouldn't be there.  Second, when you do swap, just swap `lib_books` (your `hold` would be of type `lib_book`, not `std::string`).  There is no need to swap each item in `lib_book`, swap the entire thing in one go -- everything inside in it will be brought in for the ride..  What if `lib_book` had 20 members.  Would you write 20 sets of code to swap each item?  No.